# Kinky CSS in answers header

Tags: bug, design

In the header for the answers sections, there are kinks in the line:

[image: Illustration of error]

where there are not on, say, Stack Overflow:

[image: How it should be]

It is the same in both Firefox 46.0 and IE11.

Perhaps someone could tweak the CSS for electronics.stackexchange?

Comment: Don't you have something better to do?

Comment: Here are EEs that love kinks...

Comment: @OlinLathrop What could possibly be better than making this site better? /me goes back to refactoring code in a noisy office.

Comment: Well, this certainly isn't the post I was expecting...

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1015/ "If you really hate someone, teach them to recognize bad kerning."

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a display artifact of the design of the tabs, interacting with the brower's magnification.

Whichever tab is selected, that tab is rendered with `class "youareherre"`, changing the `border-bottom-color` to `#fff` instead of `#eaeaea`. When viewed at the normal 100% magnification, the white bottom border makes the selected tab look like it is attached to the active page. The gray bottom border of the non-selected tabs is meant to line up with the top border of the active page.

However, when magnification is 90%, the visual elements get slightly misaligned, causing a visible artifact. The normally hidden top border of the questions page, is no longer covered by the header line, and so the non-selected tabs effectively get a thicker 2-pixel line, and the selected tab gets a 1-pixel line. The selected tab's white bottom border is drawn just one pixel above the page's gray border.

This has the effect of making a thicker gray line between the non-selected tabs and the content below.

Stackoverflow.com actually does have the same feature. It looks different when rendered under different magnification.

90% magnification (using chrome browser Version 50.0.2661.94 m):
[image: capture at 90%]
[image: capture SO at 90%]

100% magnification (using chrome browser Version 50.0.2661.94 m):
[image: capture at 100%]
[image: capture SO at 100%]

125% magnification (using chrome browser Version 50.0.2661.94 m):
[image: capture at 125%]
[image: capture SO at 125%]

Personally I think I can live with it. The red top border makes it unambiguous which tab is active.